Movie in which teenagers learn/train alone in black environment
I've seen a space related movie where teenagers learn/train alone in a dark room that has reversed cone-shaped holes, each kid being in one. They learn very fast and if I remember right they compete amongst themselves.
Edit:
USA space/action movie, English language.
The training part is just a scene and not the main subject. I'm pretty sure someone is training the kids.
During the training process they watch a screen. Do math exercises. Fight.
I saw the movie in cinema. 2006 - 2012

Why did this got down voted ?

Because there's not a huge amount of detail to go on/search for. Do you remember anything else? I know you put a year range in your tags, but your should mention in your question approx year of release. Live action, animated, etc.

Also, was it a theatrical release? TV Movie? Video? As far as genre, was it a serious Sci-Fi movie? Comedy/parody? Aimed towards adults or a younger audience? Do you know what the main subject was?

This was done in Star Trek (from 2009).  Here is a clip of that scene, showing the inverted cones with a kid standing in each one, learning.

